# Fit Image to completed frame

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am creating a image view. but my image is displaying in center and also a bottom layout width is not decreasing .This is my code:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.GalleryTouch
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom"
        android:text="                                     Thank you" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use fill parent for using the image to fill the complete screen ,here i am changing in your code may be it 'll work for you-

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

     <it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.GalleryTouch
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
          />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom"
        android:text=" THank you" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank You. it is working something good . but Image is not taking completed area of imageview or phone screen. is it problem made by pre-define library "it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.GalleryTouch"

Comment: yes if after this image is not coming properly to fit the screen so it relate to it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.GalleryTouch just try to give that grid view as 1 column if u r using grid view

Comment: thank  you , you are correct . sorry , i can't give you point due to not have minimum pass point to give you . thank you

Comment: but atleast can accept the answer if it was somehow useful to you.

Comment: reputation problem . display error message must be 15. but i have 6 now time . when i have , i will 100% give one :)

Comment: i think now u got the reputation for voting

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the property `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for `ImageView` in your XML file.